# Create the same multiple folder in all sub directory folders from excel list using VBA

Tags: excel, directory, vba

I am currently trying to set up a directory and am trying to work out the vba code to create a directory from an excel spreadsheet.

- `Column A` of the worksheet lists the required folder names.
- This is an example of what I want the final directory to look like.

  1. VIC\Branch 1\Folder A
  2. VIC\Branch 1\Folder B
  3. VIC\Branch 2\Folder A
  4. VIC\Branch 2\Folder B
     etc

I have been able to create the state and branch level folders but am stuck at creating the same five folders in every branch folder. If anyone could help the vb code to create these folders it would be most appreciated.

Below is the code I used to create the branch folders with each state directory. I ran it for each state list and just changed the directory location

Thank you

```
Sub MakeFolders()
Dim xdir As String
Dim fso
Dim lstrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
lstrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To lstrow
xdir = "C:\Users\Nikki\Shared\VIC\" & Range("A" & i).Value
If Not fso.FolderExists(xdir) Then
fso.CreateFolder (xdir)
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array for the subfolders and loop through that for each of your 1st level folders.

Change this line
`vSubfolders = Array("A", "B", "C")`
to add/remove your second level folders

```
Sub MakeFolders()
Dim xdir As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim lstrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim vSubfolders
Dim vSubFolder

vSubfolders = Array("A", "B", "C")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
lstrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To lstrow
xdir = "C:\Users\Nikki\Shared\VIC\" & Range("A" & i).Value
If Not fso.FolderExists(xdir) Then
fso.CreateFolder (xdir)
End If
For Each vSubFolder In vSubfolders
If Not fso.FolderExists(xdir & "\" & vSubFolder) Then
fso.CreateFolder (xdir & "\" & vSubFolder)
End If
Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```